# Generate title cased fields with JPA/Spring Boot on Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a POJO like this (Groovy)

```
class User {
  @Column(name = 'Username')
  String username
  @Column(name = 'EmailAddress')
  String emailAddress
}
```

Nothing I do seems to force JPA to generate the schema like this:

```
create table User (
  Username varchar(64),
  EmailAddress varchar(64)
)
```

What I get is `username varchar` and  `email_address varchar`. What configuration option can be set to fix this?

Comment: Did you mean `@Column(name = 'Username', length = 64)` ?

Comment: Upper ch racters in postgresql is evil really, I don't advice to use them in any name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL unquoted names are case-insensitive. 
So Username and username are the same.

If you want to have case-sensitive name you have to put the names in double-quotes.

But I would recommend never to use case-sensitive name.

About the length YCF_L is right there is missing the length parameter in the @Column annotation.

```
@Column(name = 'Username', length = 64)
```

Comment: I agree with you but I would like to talk about the length also

Comment: I added the length parameter to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use postGresql Dialect in order to use case sensitive table names, update/add dialect to either `PostgreSQLDialect` or `PostgreSQL82Dialect`

modify your application.properties to use,

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```